# Why the current item's values ​are not shown in the mail which is sent by SP Designer Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, list-item, sharepoint-email

I have created several Workflows with SharePoint Designer 2013. But every time I  send an email with some ​​current item values in the email body , no values appear.

Why values don't appear in the email body ?

Perhaps with a screenshot it will be better !

Here it is the mail which was created in Workflow

[image]

And here it is the result of the recieved mail

[image]

Comment: Perhaps, with a screen shot, it will be better :

Answer (score 0):

Well, I suppose your **Current items values inside Emails are not properly binding**. Please delete the existing Bindings which have format like : *[%Current Item:Summary Links%]* & then freshly bind them as per the Screen-shot --

*Note: Please do not copy-paste the content from another designer WF email as the current item value bindings are lost. Only the email text appears*

[image]